# How to configure Cisco Aironet 1200 in windows 10?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a cisco aironet 1200 router but there is no way to configure it from Windows 10.

How do I configure it?

Comment: The Aironet 1200 is an Access Point, not a router... Just factory default it, connect it to your network, check your DHCP assignments for it's MAC address to determine the IP address or scan the network with an IP subnet scanner (Angry IP or Advanced IP Scanner for example) and put the IP address into your web browser. The OS you are using is not relevant. Or you can use a Cisco programming cable and a serial terminal program, again, not OS dependent, so your question is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

#### There is no way to configure it from Windows 10

Follow the instructions in the [Quick Start Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/1200/ios/quick/guide/12iosqsg.pdf):

> **Obtaining and Assigning an IP Address**
>
> To browse to the access point’s Express Setup page, you must either
>   obtain or assign the access point’s IP address using one of the
>   following methods:
>
> - Connect to the access point console port and assign a static IP address.
> - Use a DHCP server (if available) to automatically assign an IP address.
>
> You can find out the DHCP-assigned IP address using one of the
>   following methods:
>
> - Connect to the access point console port and use the show ip interface brief command to display the IP address.
> - Query the DHCP server using the access point’s MAC address to identify the IP address. Your network administrator can do this.
>
> **Using the Access Point’s Console Port**
>
> You can identify or assign an IP address using the access point’s
>   console port and a terminal emulator for all operating systems.
>   However, if your computer’s operating system is Windows CE, Linux, or
>   Mac OS, you must use the access point’s command-line console.
>
> To access the command-line console, connect a DB-9 to RJ-45 serial
>   cable (Cisco part number AIR-CONCAB-1200) from your PC to the RS-232
>   console port on the access point. Then open a terminal emulator to
>   view the express setup screen and identify the IP address. Use these
>   port settings for the terminal session: 9600 baud, no parity, 8 data
>   bits, 1 stop bit, and no flow control.
>
> **Configuring the Access Point**
>
> After you have determined or assigned the access point’s IP address,
>   you can open the access point management pages and initially configure
>   the access point. The access point must be connected to your network
>   and your PC must be on the same subnet. Follow these steps.
>
> 1. Open your Internet browser. You must use Microsoft Internet Explorer (version 4.0 or later) or Netscape Navigator/ Communicator
>      (version 4.0 or later).
> 2. Enter the access point’s IP address in the browser address line and press Enter. The Summary Status screen appears.
> 3. From the Summary Status screen, click Setup and Express Setup. The Express Setup screen appears.

Source [Quick Start Guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/access_point/1200/ios/quick/guide/12iosqsg.pdf)